# Shuffle dataframe values on condition that no element appears in its original position (derangement)

Tags: python, pandas, permutation, shuffle

Python 3.10/Pandas 1.1.3

Given this code:

```
import pandas as pd
 
data = {'a': ['AA','BB','CC','DD', 'EE', 'FF', 'GG'],
        'b': [11, 22, 33, 44, 55, 66, 77],
        }
 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['a','b'])
df.a

print (df)
```

which produces:

```
    a   b
0  AA  11
1  BB  22
2  CC  33
3  DD  44
4  EE  55
5  FF  66
6  GG  77
```

I need to understand how I can shuffle the values of column `b` with the condition that the resulting dataframe is not allowed to have any `b` values be associated with their original `a` values.

Comment: Wow, all 3 answers so far work perfectly, using different approaches.  Well done.  I am going to choose the best answer based on fewest lines of codes and fastest execution.

Comment: what if `b` has duplicate values? Like: `[11,22,11,...]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following function to find a way to remap your column:

```py
def derange(x):
  res = x
  while np.any(res == x):
    res = np.random.permutation(x)
  return res
```

Then just apply it to any column:

```py
df['b'] = derange(df['b'])
```

The method is to generate permutations until one is good enough. The expected number of attempts is `(n/(n-1))^n` which converges to `e` very quickly.

Note that for `n=1` the expectation actually tends to infinity which makes sense as you cannot derange such a list.

Derangement can also be performed deterministically so here it is, for completeness:

```py
def derange2(x):
  n = len(x)
  for i in range(n - 1):
    j = random.randrange(i + 1, n)
    x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```

This function actually transforms the list in-place.

You can also have a version that modifies `pandas` columns in-place:

```py
def derange3(df, col):
  n = df.shape[0]
  for i in range(n - 1):
    j = random.randrange(i + 1, n)
    df.iat[i, col], df.iat[j, col] = df.iat[j, col], df.iat[i, col]
```

Comment: All 3 answers so far get the job done.  I'm choosing this as the answer since it least lines of code, executes the fastest, and has a good detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Let us doing with `numpy`

```
def rnd(l):
    l1 = l.copy()
    while True:
        np.random.shuffle(l1)
        if any(l == l1):
            break
        else:
            return l1
        
df.b = rnd(df.b.values)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can shuffle the index until it doesn't match the original index any more and then sort `df['b']` using the new shuffled indices and assign this new array back to `df['b']`:

```
idx = df.index.tolist()
while (idx == df.index).any():
    np.random.shuffle(idx)
        
df['b'] = df['b'][idx].values
```

Comment: Neat. `while (idx == df.index).any(): np.random.shuffle(idx)` seems like cleaner code.